# how can i make a progress bar when i upload a image to my firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

i want to make a progress to show the user how much of a file is uploaded so he wont exit n middle of uploading can anyone help me with how can i make a progress bar in vue js

i'm using this firebase code to show the percentage i have used v-model and p tags to show the percentage but nothing works

methods:{

```
uploadfiles(e) {
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var path = "users/" + user.uid + "/attachments/" + Date.now() + ".jpg";
  var storageRef = storage.ref(path);
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
      task.on('state_changed');
    function progress (self, snapshot){
      var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
        console.log('this is image =',percentage);
          self.progress = percentage;
           console.log(progress);
    }

    task.then(snapshot => {
      console.log("image uploaded successfully");
      //saveMessageInDatabase(newmessagedata);
      return task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then(url => {
      console.log("download url of image", url);
      this.username.image = url;
      console.log(this.username.image);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // hideMessageDialog();
      console.log("image uploaded error");
    });
}
```

}
HTML

```
  <p>{{this.progress}}%</p>

   <progress max="100"  :style="{width: progress+'%'}" value="0"> 
 </progress> 

<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="this.progress" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" :style="{width: this.progress+'%'}"></div>

    <input id="pic" type="file"  @change="uploadfiles">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function progress (self, snapshot){
      var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
      console.log('this is image =',percentage);
      self.progress = percentage ;
    console.log(progress);
  }
```

Parse `this` to function `progress` as `self`.
From `this.progress = percentage ;`, `this` is means of `function progress`.